# Getting the Dimensions of an inputed image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In order to upload an image and while stopping it from taking up too much space I have written this code. Unfortunately it shall result in the image becoming distorted. Is it possible to take the width and height of the inputed image and then dividing that by 10 in order to scale the image down while stopping it from becoming deformed. And then "posting" it.

HTML:

```
    <button  id="publish-button" onclick="publish();">Publish</button>
    <p>Images</p>
    <input id="image-file" type="file"/>
    <ul id="posts"></ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var image = document.getElementById("posts");
var image = document.createElement("img");
var imageInput = document.getElementById('image-file');
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageInput.files[0]);
image.style.height =  100;
image.style.width =  100;
para.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: changing the display size of an image won't change the size of the actual image data - for display purposes, you can set width or height to a value in `px` and the other to auto, so it won't distort in the view, but ... again .. this doesn't change the image data at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small class here instead and in the class set `width` to `auto` and `max-height` to `100px` in order to scale the image down and keeping the aspect ratio same.

```js
function publish(e) {
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

  image.className = "img";
  
  image.onload = function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src)
  }
};
```

```css
.img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="image-file" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="publish(event)" /><br/>
<img id="img" />
```

Also, if you are putting the dynamic images inside the `<p>` tag, then you don't even need to add the class in js code, you can just modify the css like:

```
p img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

and it would add the css to all images inside the `<p>` tag, including current & future elements.